# How to use FactoryGirl to create an attribute called "alias"?

Tags: ruby, factory-bot

I'm just wondering whether it's possible to create an attribute called "alias" using FactoryGirl, since alias is a reserved word in Ruby.

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :blah do
    name "dummy"
    alias "dummy"
  end
end
```

I've tried various combinations of escaping things but can't get anything useful to work.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Ruby doesn't know whether you're trying to call a method called `alias` or alias one method as another, and defaults to the latter. You can disambiguate by doing

```
self.alias "dummy"
```

ie, by explicitly specifying the receiver. This is usually the way to go in other cases where it is ambiguous whether you are calling a method or doing something else e.g.

```
self.foo = 'bar'
```

to call the `foo=` method rather than create a local variable called foo.

For a [small number of field names](https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_girl/blob/master/lib/factory_girl/definition_proxy.rb#L3) this won't work. Factory girl's DSL uses `method_missing` so if the DSL object has a method of that name it will be called instead. In those cases you can do what the DSL sugar normal does for you and call `add_attribute` directly:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :blah do
    add_attribute :name, "some value"
  end
end
```

is the same as

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :blah do
    name "some value"
  end
end
```

Comment: Using `self.alias` did the trick.  I was positive I had already tried that though.  (-:  Thanks!

Comment: Was just having this problem where my model has an attribute called "end". `self.end` makes it work.

Answer (score 2):

Define a variable for the `factory .. do` block and call methods on it.

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :blah do |f|
    f.name "dummy"
    f.alias "dummy"
  end
end
```