# Table column name is also ruby reserved keyword

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, factory-bot

I am using Factory Girl to help in creating records for testing.  The problem I am having isn that on of the fields in a table is named 'alias', which is a reserved ruby keyword. This is what I am trying to do:

```
factory :time_zone do
  id 4
  name "Eastern"
  abbreviation "EST"
  utc "-5"
  alias "America/New_York"
end
```

I get an error when running tests.

When I tried using self.alias  "America/New_York", This is the error that I get.

```
Failure/Error: FactoryGirl.create(:time_zone, id: 4 , name:"Eastern" , utc:"-5") NoMethodError: undefined method `alias=' for #<TimeZone id: 4, name: "Eastern", abbreviation: "EST", utc: -5>
```

Note: The self.alias does work on my local machine, but the test is failing using jenkins service for monitoring tests.

How do I make this work?

Thanks

Comment: See the following question, which I believe is a duplicate of yours http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9309891/how-to-use-factorygirl-to-create-an-attribute-called-alias

Comment: Your life will be a lot easier if you just use a different name for the field.

Comment: yes, I saw that post and tried self.alias "America/New_York" and I got this error:  Failure/Error: FactoryGirl.create(:time_zone, id: 4 , name:"Eastern" , utc:"-5")
     NoMethodError:
       undefined method `alias=' for #<TimeZone id: 4, name: "Eastern", abbreviation: "EST", utc: -5>

Comment: Yes it would be alot easier to change the field name, but the higher uppers wouldn't go for it.

Answer (score 4):

As others have commented, your life will be easier it you use a different name for that column, however if you want to stick with it, you can make factory_girl work by using `add_attribute`.  Your factory would then look like:

```
factory :time_zone do
  id 4
  name "Eastern"
  abbreviation "EST"
  utc "-5"
  add_attribute :alias, "America/New_York"
end
```

Comment: I tried add_attribute and it fails also on the jenkins server. I does work on my dev machine though.  I wish that I could just rename field but am not able to.

Comment: Is your database schema the same in both environments?  What's the error you're getting on the Jenkins server?

Comment: yes, the db schema is identical.  the error on the jenkins server is "Failure/Error: FactoryGirl.create(:time_zone, id: 4 , name:"Eastern" , utc:"-5") NoMethodError: undefined method `alias=' for #<TimeZone id: 4, name: "Eastern", abbreviation: "EST", utc: -5>"